# Variable length coding, how many bits to read?

Tags: bit-manipulation, iso

Here is the snapshot from the AAC ISO standard:
[image]

How can I tell how many bits should I read for **hcod_sf**? What does **1..19** stands for?

Answer (score 0):

VLC (*Variable Length Coding*) stands for a variable amount of bits being used. So in your example the current value consists of 1 to 19 bits.

This may seem confusing at first, but it follows a strict logic. There will surely be a table in the *Appendix* defining what bit combination represents what value.

Each value is represented by a certain - unique - bit combination which can be determined by *serially* reading bits.

**For example this table:**

```
0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx = value = 0  ( 1 bit length )
10xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx = value = 1  ( 2 bit length )
110xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx = value = 2  ( 3 bit length )
1110xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx = value = 3  ( 4 bit length )
...
1111111111111111110 = value = 18 ( 19 bit length )
```

In this example a `0` denotes the *end-of-the-value* which, in combination with the `1`s, encode the VLC value. As being said, you have to read the bitstream serially to get the *length in bits* of the value, so in this example you'd have to check for a trailing `0`.

In reality, these tables are often constructed with [Huffman Coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) and hence are more complex than in this example. You will surely find the table for your translation in the aforementioned *Appendix* of the specification.

> How can I tell how many bits should I read for hcod_sf?

You can only determine the number of bits to be read by reading them. Practically you read (at least 19) bits at once and then evaluate how many of these bits belong to the value (often by using a *table*).

> What does 1..19 stands for?

It stands for the minimum (1) and maximum (19) amount of bits in this particular value.

**Finally:**
It's quite tricky to implement this, so knowing the [BMI instruction set extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Sets) is really helpful for an x86 way of handling of this.